# Xamarin Forms: How to make each Carousel Page a different Color

Tags: forms, xamarin, carousel

I created Carousel view that contains a Collection of Slides. Each slide contains and image, message, and Color. It is stored in an ObservableCollection. I have three colors in the collection. The first slide/page should be yellow, second should be Red, and third should be blue. The issue I have is, when the app initiates all of the slides are blue in the carousel. I need each slide/page to have different colors.

```
 Carousel.ItemsSource =   slides = new ObservableCollection<Slides>(new[]
            {
                new Slides("money", "Some Description", BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow),
                new Slides("money", "Some Description2", BackgroundColor = Color.Red),
                new Slides("money", "Some Description3",BackgroundColor = Color.Blue)});



<Control:CarouselViewControl x:Name="Carousel"
                             ShowIndicators="True"
                             BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                             CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="Black">
   <Control:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Padding="60,30,60,0">
              <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
          </ContentView>
          <ContentView Grid.Row="1" Padding="20,50,20,0">
              <Label Text="{Binding Message}" TextColor="black"
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     FontSize="Large"/>

          </ContentView>

      </Grid>

       </DataTemplate>
   </Control:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</Control:CarouselViewControl>
```

I expect each page to have different colors.

Comment: Which Carousel View are you using? But in general you need to bind the color at ItemTemplate level.

Comment: could you show your `Slides`,do you bind the data correctly ？

Comment: I'm using a carousel plugin called CarouselView.FormsPlugin. The slides are added in the ObservableCollection at the top of the xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `BackgroundColor` for the `CarouselViewControl`, which will set it for the whole view, not the distinct slides.

Furthermore, the items stored in `ItemsSource` do not represent any views in the `CarouselViewControl`, but rather data objects. Just because an object in the `ItemsSource` collection has a value `BackgroundColor`, the `BackgroundColor` of the respective view in the `CarouselViewControl` ain't set automagically.

To set the background of the pages you'll have to operate from within the `DataTemplate` and bind the `BackgroundColor` property of the `Grid` to the respective property of `Slide`.

```xml
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"> <!-- Bind the grids BackgroundColor to the one of the Slide -->
    <!-- the grids content -->
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```